# How do I access my phone (not my SD card) from my computer?

Tags: internal-storage

I have an MyTouch 4G from TMobile. It's running android 2.3.4. How do I put put a file and delete files from the phone itself, not just the SD card?

Comment: What do you mean the phone itself? Do you mean the internal sd card? Do you mean the root file system?

Comment: The internal memory of the phone.

Comment: Which is...? That could mean the root system area, or the Internal SD card. Please be specific :)

Comment: So if I take out the SD card out, the memory that the phone runs out then. I don't know what it's called, but just the hard drive built into the phone.

Comment: The thing is, that could mean the root system, or the internal storage SD card (normally /emmc or something). I will post an answer now though :)

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You could install the [Android SDK](http://developer.android.com/sdk/index.html) on your computer. This would give you the possibility to access your device's storage via the command line using e.g. `adb push` and `adb pull`. If that's not the level of comfort you want, there are also graphical tools utilizing ADB:

[ADB FileExplorer](http://forum.xda-developers.com/showthread.php?t=1821601) is a minimalistic frontend to copy files from/to the device. It's freely available from the XDA developers (simply follow the link). It is written in Java, and thus should run on nearly all operating systems used on desktop computers.

[image: ADB FileExplorer]

If you want a little more comfort, then there's also [ADBBrowser](http://sourceforge.net/projects/adbbrowser/). Available for Linux and Windows (32-bit and 64-bit), it offers also an app-browser. And last but not least, there's [QtADB](http://qtadb.wordpress.com/) available for Linux, Mac and Windows (again 32-bit and 64-bit), full of useful features like file manager, app manager, device information, SMS, shell, screenshots, logcat, backup/restore... Take a pick.

[image: QtADB]

Of course, there are many more possibilities. If your device is rooted, there are several apps available on the Playstore which permit full access to the local file system remotely.

Comment: Why won't the ADBBrowser work? This: http://chipperyman573.com/Capture.PNG is what it looks like.

Comment: Because you have to install the Android SDK first, and the adb executable must be in the path (as it looks like). Please see the installation instructions of that application.

Answer (score 0):

If you mean the Internal SD Card (where pictures etc are stored if they aren't stored on the internal SD Card), then this is mounted along with the external SD card when you connect your phone to the computer.

If you mean the root file system, (I.E where the Android system files are), then this can be done, but not directly.

You would have to do it using an app via FTP, and you would have to be rooted to see the vast majority of the files.

The app [SSH Droid](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=berserker.android.apps.sshdroid) allows you to turn your device into an SSH/SFTP server, which allows you to use FTP to connect to the internal file system (where the main system files are stored) of your device, using an FTP client (Nautilus, Windows Explorer, Filezilla for example).

When doing this, be careful not to delete any files that could be important in the functioning of your device, and like I said - root will be needed to do most things here.

Comment: Alternatively, adb is another means of accessing the internal memory, though you'd want a level of comfort with the command line.